# WooCommerce checkout, place order even with disabled=true

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

Is it possible in Woocommerce checkout to send a order when using:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['custom_attributes']          = array('disabled' => true);
```

The thing is I have some fields I don't want the users to be able to mess with, but I still want woocommerce to actually use them.
But its not possible to go past the "place order" when you have a required field disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `1 hour` trying to figure it out, `20 sec` after posting on SO - i solved it :)

```
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly' => true);
```

`disabled -> readonly`